# Wrapper does not take it's Intrinsic Content Size as sum of it's children and constraints between them

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout, ccuiviewwrapper

I am creating popup that measures it's size (here only height) from the its content.

Popup consists of two half (top and bottom). I have decided to wrap top half into separate wrapper view for clean code, so I have added UILabels, UIImages etc. into it in the separate method, but now I am facing problem with it.

Their size for AutoLayout is 0! So, I have a size of popup less than needed:

[image: Not enough size]

But if I remove wrapper then everything is OK:

[image: Normal size]

I feel that it is enough data for iOS to render it correctly, but I don't know the command to force iOS to calculate size of wrapper basing on sizes of its subviews and constraints.

I have tried `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` on the wrapper, but didn't help.

I am marking up from the code, so I don't forget to set *Translates autoresizing masks into constraints* to false for child views.

Comment: “I don't know the command to force iOS to calculate size of wrapper basing on sizes of its subviews and constraints.” Okay, now you do:    https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622624-systemlayoutsizefitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It is figured out that I forgot to joint top and bottom of wrapper with top of top view and bottom of bottom view respectively.